how to provide user interface to select a file during an installation, using Visual Studio setup project?
I am using Visual Studio setup project to create an msi. I need to get a file, selected from the user during installation, and do certain action based on the selected file. I am trying to use custom actions. Added custom action, added installer class, adding UI using User Interface editor of my setup project. On my right click on User Interface editor, I see dialogs to add checkBox, radio button, text Box, but not able to find a dialog, which can give option for user to browse a file on his machine.
I found some links, which talk about editing the pre-existing dialogs using orca tool. But not sure which dialog should be picked as a reference for the same. Is there a way, I can embed a OpenFileDialog inside an existing dialog? Thanks for any inputs in this direction.
I tried editing the dialogs found on 1033 folder, and able to edit a few details of a CheckBox dialog and able to view and add it in my User Interface Editor. But not able to find a way to add a Browse option.
I tried to show a UI through my Installer class, Install method, which could take input from user, but when I test the msi, my UI goes in the backgroud, so does not really give an option for user interaction.
If there is another way to get file upload from user, during installation, please suggest.
